# How to decide if a factorial is a multiple of certain number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial

How to decide if a factorial is a multiple of certain number?

For example, if I have to decide whether $123!$ is a multiple of $4$ or not what should be the procedure?

Comment: @xXLemonProgrammerXx if the number if smaller for eg in this case i can write 123! in terms of 4n but what if the number is larger than factorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the number is smaller than the factorial it certainly is a multiple. In you example, $123! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times ... \times 123$. It contains 4 thus, 4 is a multiple. $123!$ can be written as $$123! = 4 \times (1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 5  \times 6 \times ...  \times 123)$$

Comment: if the number if smaller for eg in this case i can write 123! in terms of 4n but what if the number is larger than factorial?

Comment: I don't have any such method in my mind. For smaller numbers you can simply write their prime factors.

Answer (score 1):

Every number less than $123$ and $123$ itself is a multiple of $123!$.  Don't forget how $n!$ is defined, $n\times(n-1)\times(n-2)\times\dots\times1$.

Comment: Thanks for the editing of the format.  Where can I find the instructions on the forum how to do that?  While you're at it, the OP has a couple of issues too, like capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

Well in the case of $4$ being a multiple of $123!$, you just have to go back to the definition of factorial. $n! = 1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\cdot
\cdot n$ and $4$ is included there. Now for bigger numbers, you could use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and write it as a product of it's prime factors. Then you could break the factorial into it's prime factors too which isn't difficult because if $p$ is a prime in $n!$, then $p \leq n$. For example, if you want to see if $6!$ is a multiple of $8$ then $$6!=1*2*3*4*5*6=2^43^25$$ and $$8=2^3$$
and $$2^3\mid 2^43^25$$